# How to read the read the pcap(packet captuer) file using python

Tags: python, pcap

I tried to read the Pcap file using the Python and Pcap file located on my local desk,
it will read the file and print the data **print(pcap_file.summary())** while I use this method in the script, But when I try to filter the SMTP layer in the pcap file it will not work I used the lib(scapy) and IDE is (Pchram), and I tried lib (dkpt) also but it will not working I use to see the pcap file in my local desk software called Wireshark when opening the file and parsing the file in Wireshark some bunch of SMTP have different src and dist port number my task looking complicate.

note: I do know why it did not print the data that expected

[ below I will give the code ]

```
from dpkt.ip import *
from scapy.all import *

def print_tcp_smtp_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet.haslayer('SMTP'):
        destination_ip = packet[IP].dst
        destination_port = packet[TCP].dport
        print(f"Destination IP: {destination_ip}, Destination Port: {destination_port}")

# Read the pcap file
pkts = rdpcap('/home/xyz/Desktop/tcpdump_cloud3.pcap')
#print(pkts.summary())

# Filter and print destination IP and port for packets with TCP and SMTP layers
for pkt in pkts:
    print_tcp_smtp_info(pkt)
```

print(pkts.summary())

Comment: You are basically saying that you did something and it did not work - without any actual details about what you exactly tried and what errors you got etc. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the part about helping others to reproduce your problem. In the current form it is basically asking for somebody coming to you, holding your hands and teaching you every tiny detail. But this site is about asking focused questions, not hiring tutors.